# Generate Fibonacci Sequence in Compile-Time using generics

Tags: generics, rust, compile-time

In C++ with template metaprogramming you can calculate the fibonacci sequence in compile-time easily in this way.

```cpp
template<int  N>
constexpr int fibonacci() {return fibonacci<N-1>() + fibonacci<N-2>(); }
template<>
constexpr int fibonacci<1>() { return 1; }
template<>
constexpr int fibonacci<0>() { return 0; }
```

But in rust you cant just pass a constant through a generic as far as I know, also I know that sometimes rust optimizes some funcions to just constants in assmebly code. Example: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Compile-time_calculation#Rust

But the conventional recursive approach of the problem is not optimized to a constant.

```rust
fn fibo(n: i32) -> i32 {
    match n {
        0 => 0,
        1 => 1,
        n => fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2),
    }
}

// Call it with
fibo(45); // It takes around 5 secs, calculated at runtime
```

Ok, to this point I can undestand that just the compiler does not know how to optimize this, but I found a way to make this calculated at compile time using Iterators!

```rust
struct Fibo(u32, u32);

impl Iterator for Fibo {
    type Item = u32;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        *self = Fibo(self.1, self.1 + self.0);
        Some(self.0)
    }
}

fn fibo() -> Fibo {
    Fibo(0, 1)
}

// Call it with
fibo().take(45).collect::<Vec<_>>()[44]; // This gets the 45th element calculated at compile-time, instantly
```

At this point I just want to know why this happens.

Comment: There are two questions here, which are _very_ different from each other. Finding a way to do the same thing with generics is not at all related to how the Rust compiler is able to optimise away this calculation.

Comment: [Here's one way to write a recursive function that uses roughly the same algorithm as the `Fibo` iterator](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4b723f06baf8e5a7121a5a1a02cf9119). It runs just as fast or faster than the `Fibo` iterator version. Of course you could write a simple iterative function instead like the one in Sven's answer, but where's the fun in that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Algorithmic Complexity

The naive way of computing the Fibonacci sequence has exponential complexity

```rust
fn fibo(n: i32) -> i32 {
    match n {
        0 => 0,
        1 => 1,
        n => fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2),
    }
}
```

You can visualize it like:

- `fibo(0)`: 1 call.
- `fibo(1)`: 1 call.
- `fibo(2)`: 3 calls -- `fibo(2)`, `fibo(1)`, `fibo(0)`.
- `fibo(3)`: 5 calls -- `fibo(3)`, `fibo(2)` (which is worth 3), `fibo(1)`.
- `fibo(4)`: 9 calls -- `fibo(4)`, `fibo(3)` (worth 5) and `fibo(2)` (worth 3).

The iterator version, however, is *completely* different. Rewritten as a function it boils down to:

```rust
fn fibo(n: i32) -> i32 {
    fn rec(i: i32, current: i32, next: i32) -> i32 {
        if i == 0 { current } else { rec(i - 1, next, current + next) }
    }

    rec(n, 0, 1)
}
```

Which executes in exactly `n + 1` steps... providing `n >= 0`.

#### But in C++ it works!

C++ compilers tend to use *memoization* for both template instantiations and constexpr evaluations. They do not *have* to, this is strictly an implementation detail, but they do for efficiency reasons.

In this instance, a memoized version of `fibo` turns exponential complexity into linear complexity, which is *much* easier to compute.

#### Doing it in Rust!

It's possible to compute fibonacci in Rust at compile-time with the current beta, which stabilizes branches in `const` functions.

See [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=beta&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6f2977b726e6be7389e2380051294ebe):

```rust
const fn fibo(n: i32) -> i32 {
    const fn rec(i: i32, current: i32, next: i32) -> i32 {
        if i == 0 { current } else { rec(i - 1, next, current + next) }
    }

    rec(n, 0, 1)
}

fn main() {
    const RESULT: usize = fibo(9) as usize;

    let array: [i32; RESULT] = [
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
        0, 1
    ];
    
    println!("{}", array[0]);
}
```

There may be a trick to express the computation at compile-time without a branch, allowing to compute `fibo` at compile-time on stable, however I am not sure rustc wouldn't perform the recursive call regardless.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to make it work on stable. While you can imitate conditionals with something like `[a, b][condition as usize]`, this won't work with recursion, since both `a` and `b` will be eagerly evaluated. Current stable has no form of conditional evaluation at all in const functions, so recursion is out of question, and current stable does not support any form of loops in const functions.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I tried `(i == 0) as i32 * current + i * rec(i - 1, next, current + next)`, however MIRI still evaluates `rec` even if `i == 0`, so no cookie ;)

Comment: I notice that your linear-recursive `fibo` has one drawback: it maxes out at `fibo(45)` whereas the naive recursive version can calculate `fibo(46)` without overflowing (even if it takes 10 minutes).

Comment: @trentcl I took care to write my iterative version in a way that it does not compute any addition beyond the one it needs to, which resulted in the additional `if` at the beginning of the function. Otherwise, you could return `a` instead of `b` in my implementation, and wouldn't need the `if`.

Comment: @Sven It's a touch subtle, but there is a way to alter the algorithm so it doesn't overflow prematurely and doesn't need the `if`. I posted a recursive interpretation in the question comments but it would obviously work iteratively as well.

Comment: @trentcl Ah, I see, the trick is to use (1, 0) instead of the usual (0, 1) as the starting vector, so the first iteration just swaps the two numbers. Now that I see it, it's quite obvious from the matrix representation of the Fibonacci iteration. I adapted the code in my answer to use this trick as well. :)

Answer (score 6):

I looked at the assembly output of your second code example, and the compiler does not seem to optimise this to a constant. Likely, something very different is going on.

The approach you call the "classic" recursive algorithm is the worst way of computing Fibonacci numbers, since the number of function invocations grows exponentially with `n`. The iterative approach is much better, since it only requires a number of iterations linearly growing with `n`. For `n = 44`, that works out to about ten trillion function invocations for the recursive approach, versus 44 loop iterations for the iterative approach. Of course the latter appears "instant" at run time, but that doesn't mean any particular compiler magic is happening here.

(For really big `n` you need arbitrary precision arithmetic, and the best approach is binary matrix powering.)

Now for your second question, how to get Rust to evaluate this at compile time. Template metaprogramming in C++ is actually a crutch for compile time computations, and Rust has a far easier approach: constant functions. Some aspects of const fns are still evolving, but in the current beta version (which will be released as stable in about two weeks), you can write the Fibonacci function in a rather straightforward way:

```
pub const fn fibo(mut n: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut a = 1;
    let mut b = 0;
    while n > 0 {
        let tmp = b;
        b += a;
        a = tmp;
        n -= 1;
    }
    b
}

pub const K: u64 = fibo(93);
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=beta&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6d2b58306d5184c171ed63acfa90dfa1))

There are also const generics in Rust, but they are unstable (and still rather buggy). It is possible that you can do something similar to the C++ template metaprogramming version, but I didn't look into it.

Comment: _Template metaprogramming in C++ is actually a crutch for compile time computations_: Careful with broad statements. In this particular case it's a crutch, and `constexpr` functions should have been used instead, but template metaprogramming has its place for _type_ manipulations.

Comment: @MatthieuM. It's not quite clear how exactly template metaprogramming is defined. I was obviously referring to this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

```rust
const fn fibo(n: i32) -> i32 {
    match n {
        0 => 0,
        1 => 1,
        n => fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2),
    }
}
const A: i32 = fibo(45);
```

This code will be computed at compile time.
But it'll take a long time to compile it and it fails to be compiled on the playground.
So rust may not optimize it.
You can also see [the mir](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bd60c21a00f3c8392c9e7ca9ea7ea5c3) and ir

Comment: This takes a long time to compile because it has exponential complexity – see the explanation in my answer.